# How to set password lock for screen programatically in android?

Tags: android, security, passwords, locking

Hi I need to know whether we can set password to our lock phone programmatically,that is we set a password inside the code and when press a button the screen will lock.I need to use because I need to find a simple method without setting security password).Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: So you want to set a password and lock peoples phones? Sounds fishy to me.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is not very clear. What is meant exactly by "set password to lock my phone"? Does the OP simply want to lock the phone? Then why is a password needed? Or does the OP want to set the password for unlocking the phone programmatically? (I hope not).

Comment: no one understand my question you all see the below answer that was what am asking for. the guys who down vote me please remeber one think if you dont know the anser dont do this type  of crap or if u  did no  understand my question please tell me to make it more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PowerManager manager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);

// Choice 1
manager.goToSleep(int amountOfTime);

// Choice 2
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = manager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "Your Tag");
wl.acquire();
wl.release();
```

and define permission in xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```